# web.skype.com for Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: web-browsers

Stumbled upon [skype in browser](http://web.skype.com), decided to try it on Raspberry Pi Zero. However, it told that I need to update my browser, so I've tried logging in with the following browser:

- Epiphany browser
- IceWeasel
- Kweb browser (interestingly, this one didn't load the page at all)
- Chromium (`apt-get chromium-browser` says it's outdated)

So the question is, whether it is possible to use skype (in browser or not), without buying [ExaGear](https://eltechs.com/product/exagear-desktop/).

Answer (score 4):

According to this blog http://blogs.skype.com/2014/11/14/please-welcome-skype-for-web-beta/

It is limited to Windows and MAC with specific browsers.  Even then a plugin is required.

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12316/what-is-the-skype-web-plugin-and-how-do-i-install-it

And it goes on to say "The Skype web plugin is not supported on Windows RT, Linux and Chromebooks"

So I don't think you are going to have any luck with this!

Comment: You can use the chat options just fine outside of Windows/Mac. And they are planning on deprecating the plugin once WebRCT is better.

Comment: @DavidMulder Skype isn't waiting for better browser support of WebRTC, which is fully supported in Chrome and Firefox on all platforms. Skype uses ORTC, a competing "standard" written by Microsoft. Any time that Microsoft says "future support for WebRTC", what they actually mean is "when we get the WebRTC standard to be changed to be more the way we like it."

Comment: Curiously, if you download [chrome browser](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2711166/enterprise-software/install-google-chrome-browser-in-debian-7.html) , **and not chromium**, you can use web.skype.com! Though I'm on intel processor

Comment: Maybe it's just a recent thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get Chromium in an odd way. You can get it by executing the following:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/7916060/+files/chromium-browser_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/7916060/+files/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_45.0.2454.85–0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb chromium-browser_45.0.2454.85–0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
```

Then, go to your File Explorer and run each .deb file with Package Installer. This should install them to your system.

The reason I think this should work is because [YouTube.com/TV](http://Youtube.com/tv), a HTML5 heavy webpage loads with a bit of lag while on Chromium. I would think that if it can load that page, it should be able to load [web.skype.com](http://web.skype.com).